# Handle Javascript confirm() with flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, sqlalchemy

I had created a confirm box with confirm() in my web application through JavaScript. But the problem is my web application is mainly based on flask, so I'm having a hard time on how to handle confirm() in flask so that I can add certain data into database through SqlAlchemy.

Is there a way to control confirm() in flask or use sqlalchemy in JavaScript ?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use sqlalchemy from client side javascript. In your confirm box, check if the user has confirmed and make an API call back to your flask server to perform your database operations.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show me any simple example on API :)